# Google map issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I am using google map in my iPhone app.
It works very fine and load the places.

But when I dissmiss a modal view - it shows a warning

```
  Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UITabBarController: 0x1d8dbff0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

after that when ever I come to Map's view - the app got crashed. Even I am not relaoding the map.

it says

```
     Did not clear context upon block exit.
```

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Please show the code where you dismiss the modal view and the exact and full text of the crash error.  This probably has nothing to do with there being a map on the view.

Comment: Sorry now I fixed first warning, the crash is not related with that.